# late binding in C

Tags: c, unix, late-binding

How can late binding can be achieved in C language?
Can anybody please provide an example.

I think it can be achieved using `dlopen` and `dlsym` but I am not sure about it.Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 16):

Late (AKA Dynamic) Binding doesn't have anything to do with dynamically loaded modules (which is what `dlopen` and `dlsym` are about) per se. Instead, it is about delaying the decision about which function is called until runtime.

In C, this is done using function pointers (which is also how virtually any C++ implementation does it for virtual functions).

One way to emulate this is to pass structs of function pointers around and then only call functions via the given function pointers.

An example:

```
typedef struct Animal {
    void (*sayHello)(struct Animal *a, const char *name);
} Animal;

static void sayQuakQuak( Animal *a, const char *name ) {
    printf( "Quak quak %s, says the duck at 0x%x!\n", name, a );
}

/* This function uses late binding via function pointer. */
void showGreeting( Animal *a, const char *name ) {
    a->sayHello( a, name );
}


int main() {
    struct Animal duck = {
        &sayQuakQuak
    };
    showGreeting( &duck, "John" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Frerich Raabe: The basic late binding mechanism can be implemented as your said, but you can use a combination of dlopen/dlclose/dlsym and pointers to function to get something like:

```
void *libraryHandle;
void (*fp)(void);

if (something)
        libraryHandle = dlopen("libmylibrary0.1");
else
    libraryHandle = dlopen("libmylibrary0.2");
fp = dlsym(libraryHandle, "my_function");
fp();
```

I think this is what Benjamin Button is looking for.

Comment: I think that Frerich did well by explaining what the concept of late/dynamic binding *actually* means.

Comment: Yes, he did very well. I just mentioned an use case.

Comment: Shared library linking is also a way of abstraction. In that way the shared library implementation/behavior may vary until the very execution time of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Frerich Raabe mentioned, it is all about delaying the decision of what function to invoke, that's it.

To emphasis that it is a general mechanism in C/C++, I love to consider the below pure C (and C style coding, i.e. - no presence of any "OO concepts") in order to grasp the early/late binding concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int divide(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int input;
    printf("main - please enter your choice of operation:1 - add, 2 - substruct, 3 - mulitply, 4 - division\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    int (*funcPointer)(int, int); 
    int a = 6, b = 2;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1: funcPointer = &add;
                break;
        case 2: funcPointer = &sub;
                break;
        case 3: funcPointer = &mul;
                break;
        case 4: funcPointer = &divide;
                break;
    }

    printf("main - running the desired function\n");

    // this is where LATE binding takes place
    int res = (*funcPointer)(a, b);
    printf("main - result of the desired function is:%d\n", res);

    // this is where EARLY binding takes place
    res = divide(a, b);
    printf("main - result of the divide function is:%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```