# Implementing the late binding without using virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can I implement my own late binding technique. I should rather say the technique to have derived class function called with base class pointer (pointing to derived class) instead of base class function, without using virtual keyword. Basically I want to replicate function overriding with another logic than using virtual keyword.

Comment: Why without `virtual` keyword? Dont use C++,  Use C and function pointers.

Comment: In C or C++? And for C or C++? And at runtime or compile time?

Comment: just curiosity, nothing related to complexity or an intention of implementing a better solution than Stroustrup.. :)

Comment: Also I want some better and simple logic. I dont want to implement the similar way as implemented by C++..
I am thinking in similar way as how MFC function calls are made hierarchy wise..

Comment: MFC function calls are often via a jump table.  Gross.

Comment: possible duplicate of [late binding in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070482/late-binding-in-c)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yes don't you think that can be one way to replicate that.